# example of Complete accumulation point

Tags: general-topology

Definition of **Complete accumulation point**:

> An **accumulation point** $x$ of a set $\color{green}{M}$ in a  topological space $S$ is a point contained in $S$ and is considered to be **complete** if and only if the intersection of $\color{green}{M}$ and  any neighborhood  of $x$ has the same cardinality as the set $\color{green}{M}$

I understand the definition but I'm looking for an example that still cannot find it, is there any intuitive examples of a  Complete accumulation point specially in the real line?

Comment: I suppose $X$ is same as $M$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I edited that

Comment: Any real number is a complete accumulation point of $\Bbb Q$ because all open intervals contain countably many rationals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$0$ is a complete accumulation point of $(0,1)$.

Comment: so here  for example the intersection of any neighborhood of $1$ and $\left(0,1\right)$ has the same cardinality as $\left(0,1\right)$?

Comment: They both have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$. @user715522

Comment: what I said is wrong?

Comment: @user715522 No I just wanted to say what that cardinality was. You did not make  a mistake.